# QR Reader On-Screen insight

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, qr-code

I want to develop a QR Reader extension that reads QR codes from the screen (Not the camera), like taken a screenshot of the QR an get the URL, I'm searching an reading the source code of authenticator.cc which have this feature but I can't figure it out, I just want some insight, don't want to get the problem solved, just a way to start, I'm building the extension with JS only.

Any suggestion is welcome, thank you!

Currently I read the authenticator source code, but can't figure out a way to start

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/captureVisibleTab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Authenticator extension smoothly reads and parses a QR code on a web page using the following steps:

1. The content script injected into web page sends the QR code's position information to the extension's background page: [Link](https://github.com/Authenticator-Extension/Authenticator/blob/c5976b63c5ff3b8c6a1e2ba5077071abf973aead/src/content.ts#L194)
2. The background page captures the QR area on the web page and converts the screenshot to a DataUrl and ImageData using canvas: [Link](https://github.com/Authenticator-Extension/Authenticator/blob/c5976b63c5ff3b8c6a1e2ba5077071abf973aead/src/background.ts#L54)
3. The DataUrl is passed to the qrReader library for parsing: [Link](https://github.com/Authenticator-Extension/Authenticator/blob/c5976b63c5ff3b8c6a1e2ba5077071abf973aead/src/background.ts#L126)
4. If the qrReader library fails to parse the data, the extension falls back to using jsQrCode: [Link](https://github.com/Authenticator-Extension/Authenticator/blob/c5976b63c5ff3b8c6a1e2ba5077071abf973aead/src/background.ts#L108)

qrReader: [Link](https://github.com/edi9999/jsqrcode)

jsQrCode: [Link](https://github.com/cozmo/jsQR)

Comment: Thanks, the extension is awesome, I have a lot to read, but this answer gave me the basic idea for what I need to do, Thank you!